# angular data not updating after server request

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a report generator written in AngularJS.  It works fine when I don't use the jQuery datepicker.  When I do use the jQuery datepicker the data coming back from the server is correct, but the front-end doesn't change.   If I go pure angular this works beautifully as I demonstrate below?  Is the answer simply, use the angular datepicker with angular code to avoid issues?

In my angularJS controller I have:

```
as.controller('ReportController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {

var currentDate = new Date();
// works
$scope.loadToday = function () {
    // not sure why this is necessary here
    currentDate = new Date();
    $scope.load();
};

// does not work 
$scope.setDateAndLoad = function (newDate) {
    $scope.currentDate = newDate;
    $scope.load();
};

$scope.decrementWeekAndLoad = function () {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);
    $scope.load();
};    


// works depending on method
$scope.load = function () {
  $scope.showTable = false;
  $scope.currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var formattedDate = $scope.currentDate.toISOString();
  $http.get('/app/client/report/${user.id}?startDate=' + formattedDate)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.report = angular.copy(data);
        // $scope.report is not getting rebound
        $scope.showTable = true;
    });
};

$scope.loadToday();
```

And is bound to the following HTML code:

```
<section id="show-client" class="first" ng-app="myApp">
<div id="reportController" class="form-group" ng-controller="ReportController">
   <div ng-hide="showTable">
        Loading . . .
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showTable">
        Behavior    {{report}} 
    </div>

    <input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="datepicker">
```

In a jQuery datepicker I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        angular.element('#reportController').scope().setDateAndLoad(newDate);
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: When you handle jQuery events (not using jqLite), wrap your code with $scope.$apply(fn) to trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: I did what you suggested with the same result . . resulted now the error of my ways, which is related to implicitly using jqLite instead of jQuery, which I believe is what happens when you include angular before jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

old order:
- angular
- jQuery
- angular (yes included twice)

new order:
- jQuery
- angular

Works as expected.